# Operating on the first element of each sublist only

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have the following list containing 2-element sublists:

```
list={{0.01, 0.037348}, {0.03, 0.165434}, {0.1, 0.263921}, {0.3, 
  0.560191}, {1., 0.968857}, {3., 1.50965}, {10., 2.36502}, {30., 
  3.07659}, {100., 3.73412}, {300., 4.4931}, {1000., 5.06818}, {3000.,
   5.65423}, {10000., 6.00944}}
```

How can I get the natural logarithm (`Log[]`) of the first element of each sublist (e.g. 0.01, 0.03.....10000) only while leaving the second one intact?. I would like this operation to apply to other sublists of different lengths.

Comment: `{Log[First[#]],Last[#]}&/@list`  will make a new list with log of the first element.

Comment: This works great! @flinty. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Or `{Log@#1, #2} & @@@ list`.  There are many similar questions and this will be signed as a duplicate.

Comment: `list[[All,1]]=Log@list[[All,1]]`

Comment: If you're ultimately planning to plot this data, you may want to look at the documentation for `ListLogPlot`, `ListLogLinearPlot`, and/or `ListLogLogPlot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fast for large lists:

```
Transpose[{Log @ #, #2} & @@ Transpose[#]] & @ list
```

> ```
> {{-4.60517, 0.037348}, {-3.50656, 0.165434}, {-2.30259, 0.263921}, {-1.20397, 0.560191}, 
> {0., 0.968857}, {1.09861, 1.50965}, {2.30259, 2.36502}, {3.4012, 3.07659}, {4.60517,  3.73412},
> {5.70378, 4.4931}, {6.90776, 5.06818}, {8.00637, 5.65423}, {9.21034, 6.00944}}
> ```

Answer (score 11):

You may use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html).

```
MapAt[Log, {All, 1}]@list
```

> ```
> {{-4.60517, 0.037348}, {-3.50656, 0.165434}, 
>  {-2.30259, 0.263921}, {-1.20397, 0.560191}, 
>  {0., 0.968857}, {1.09861, 1.50965}, 
>  {2.30259, 2.36502}, {3.4012, 3.07659}, 
>  {4.60517, 3.73412}, {5.70378, 4.4931}, 
>  {6.90776, 5.06818}, {8.00637, 5.65423}, 
>  {9.21034, 6.00944}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

In addition, in v 12.0 and greater, you may use [SubsetMap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html)

```
SubsetMap[Log, list, {All,1}]
```

> {{-4.60517, 0.037348}, {-3.50656, 0.165434}, {-2.30259, 0.263921}, {-1.20397, 0.560191}, {0., 0.968857}, {1.09861, 1.50965}, {2.30259, 2.36502}, {3.4012, 3.07659}, {4.60517, 3.73412}, {5.70378, 4.4931}, {6.90776, 5.06818}, {8.00637, 5.65423}, {9.21034, 6.00944}}

Answer (score 3):

```
newlist=Table[{Log[list[[k]]],list[[k]]},{k,1,Length[list]}]
```

is inelegant but will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
Query[All, {1 -> Log}] @ list
```

{{-4.60517, 0.037348}, {-3.50656, 0.165434}, {-2.30259,
0.263921}, {-1.20397, 0.560191}, {0., 0.968857}, {1.09861,
1.50965}, {2.30259, 2.36502}, {3.4012, 3.07659}, {4.60517,
3.73412}, {5.70378, 4.4931}, {6.90776, 5.06818}, {8.00637,
5.65423}, {9.21034, 6.00944}}

Map `Log` over first and `Log10` over last column:

```
Query[All, {1 -> Log, -1 -> Log10}] @ list;
```

To `Query` rows omit the `All`:

```
Query[{1 -> Log, -1 -> Log10}] @ list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list={{0.01, 0.037348}, {0.03, 0.165434}, {0.1, 0.263921}, {0.3, 
  0.560191}, {1., 0.968857}, {3., 1.50965}, {10., 2.36502}, {30., 
  3.07659}, {100., 3.73412}, {300., 4.4931}, {1000., 5.06818}, {3000.,
   5.65423}, {10000., 6.00944}}

Cases[list, {a_, b_} :> {Log[a], b}, 1]
Replace[list, {a_, b_} :> {Log[a], b}, {1}]
SequenceReplace[list, {{a_, b_}} :> {Log[a], b}]
{list[[All, 1]] // Log, list[[All, 2]]} // Transpose
MapThread[Compose, {{Log, Identity}, #}] & /@ list
```

> {{-4.60517, 0.037348}, {-3.50656, 0.165434}, {-2.30259,
> 0.263921}, {-1.20397, 0.560191}, {0., 0.968857}, {1.09861,
> 1.50965}, {2.30259, 2.36502}, {3.4012, 3.07659}, {4.60517,
> 3.73412}, {5.70378, 4.4931}, {6.90776, 5.06818}, {8.00637,
> 5.65423}, {9.21034, 6.00944}}